# Run jquery every time the grid is populated and loop through all the rows of gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I want the jquery file run every time the Grid is populated and the jquery file should
 loop through the gridview and perform some action based on certain conditions.
In my grid I have a column called StatusId in the gridview and based on Statuid I want to set the text for the label which is inside another column. I am trying to accomplish this using jQuery. I don't know where I am going wrong.

I have an external JS file called Setstatus.js

StatusId is a bound field in the gridview.
lblStatus is a label in the template field of the gridview.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#<%=gvAsgnments.ClientID%>')
                 .find('tr')
                 .each(function (row) {
                     $(this).each(function (col) {
                         if (($.trim($(this).find("input[id*='StatusId']").val() === 0))) {
                             $("input[id*='lblStatus']", $(this)).val('New');
                             $("input[id*='StatusId']", $(this)).style.display = 'block';
                         }
                     });
                 });

});
```

I am referring to Setstatus.js in my aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Admin.js" ></script>
```

The jquery file does not produce any results. What am I misssing.

sample HTMl:

```
   <div>
        <table class="CNIGridView" cellspacing="0" rules="all" align="center" border="1" id="MainContent_gvAsgnments" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr class="CNIGridViewHeader">
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Status">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Claim">Claim</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Claimant">Claimant</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Date">Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">StatusId</th>
            </tr>
                    <tr class="CNIGridViewRow">
                  <td>
                           <span id="MainContent_gvAdminActiveAsgnments_lblStatus_0"></span>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                           <span id ="MainContent_gvAdminActiveAsgnments_lblClaim_0">MH001025</span>
                          </td>
                           <td>
                          <span id="MainContent_gvAdminActiveAsgnments_lblClaimant_0">Deborah</span>
                           </td>
                           <td>10/2/2011 12:00:00 AM</td>
                <td>0</td>
                   </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance

BB

Answer (score 1):

Is it not executing or just not producing results? There's a definite difference.  Have you opened up a javascript console or debugger to see if any errors are occurring on the page?

One thought - you say that lblStatus is a label. If it's truly an HTML label, then `input[id*='lblStatus']` won't work as a selector. It should be `label[id*='lblStatus']`. Additionally, I don't think you set the text of a label element using `val()`, you would use `text()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. When i debug I can see the function executes but doesn't produce any results. I made the changes you mentioned still no success.

Comment: Can you include a snippet of what the html looks like after it has been rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the Asp.Net labels, the label will not actually have an ID of whatever you specify in your code. The easiest way to attach this is to use the CssClass property to give them each an identifier and address them using that in your selector.

As for your rebinding the GridView what method are you using to update it?

Comment: the gridview is inside a multiview <pre><code>  <asp:MultiView ID="mvAdmin" runat="server">  
       <asp:View ID="viewActive" runat="server">  
        <asp:GridView ID="gvAsgnments" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" align ="center" > </code></pre>  .  For binding I use databind method.

Comment: I think the ID issue is why he's using the `*=` operator.  http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: I have not had much luck with the contains operator and I think you would get better performance with the class selector than comparing each ID in the DOM.

Comment: From your question it sounded as though AJAX may be involved. Are you using UpdatePanels or anything like that?

Comment: Then using the CssClass should work for you. It is typically how I grab these kinds of things for jQuery.